# Laravel: Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, webpack, prototype

In my resource/app.js I require my own written validation script. I get the following warning when compiling (*npm run dev*) my javascript files.

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /resources/js/myvendor/small-form-validator.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (2:13):
```

**My Files:**

**app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');
require('./myvendor/small-form-validator');
```

**/resources/js/myvendor/small-form-validator.js**

```
class SmallFormValidator {
    errMsgs = {
        required: 'This field is required!',
        string: 'Not valid string.',
        ...
```

**My package.json**

```
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0"
    }
}
```

The system complains about the assignment operator ("**=**" character) after errMsgs = {...}.

Is the problem that I wrote my javascript in Class Style instead of Prototype Style?

**Updated**

The solution in my case was to create in root an new .babelrc file with the order to load the Babel plugin-proposal-class-properties plugin.

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}
```

*See the correct answear from codedge!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a `.babelrc` in the root of your project and add

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}
```

Then run `npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` to install the package and then `npm run watch` (respectively `npm run dev`) to compile everything.

Comment: This solution works for me. It is possible to config this plugin in the webpack.mix.js? to have all settings in one file?